# Using vlc to batch generate snapshots say every 2-3 minutes or os?

Tags: debian, unix, batch, vlc-media-player, snapshot

Is there a way to batch generate snapshots every 2-3 minutes or so in Debian. I have a video of approximately 15 minutes and while I could use hotekey 's' to manually generate snapshots . Using vlc 2.2.4 Weathermax.

Comment: vlc probably has this, but if not numerous programs can do it, rtfm :)

Comment: could you share a few application names in debian or unix space which can do this ?

Comment: I don't use linux but I've heard other people mention such programs. Just google video thumbnails in linux.